Git failed with fatal error. Early EOF fetch pack: invalid index-index pack output
While cloning a repo, I'm getting an error

Git failed with fatal error. Early EOF fetch pack: invalid index-pack output

I am able to clone successfully from my local PC, but on on-premise servers, I am getting this error.
Can anyone please help me?
I tried some compression settings
git config --global core.compression 9 repack

